# How can I prevent git remote pushes from a specific clone?

Tags: git, push

I do not think this is not a duplicate of other posts. The typical question is "How can I prevent pushes into my remote branch.", ostensibly from all clones. I am turning the question on its head - how can I prevent pushes **from this clone**, but still allow pulls? It's ok for other clones to pull and push, but I want **this** clone to only pull. The solution can be either per branch or over the whole clone; I can work with either.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be misunderstanding the question, but I believe you can set the remote push url to something invalid so it will fail when you attempt to push:

```
git remote set-url --push origin no_push
```

Comment: I figured it would be simple. But not that simple! Thanks!